# Как прибавить к времени до ровного значения?

Tags: php, дата

У меня в системе есть автоматические задачи при изменении статуса клиента, автоматически ставится задача у которой есть значение "выполнить через N часов", например через 480 минут.

Ну пример время когда был поставлен статус: 2015-04-24 16:51:06

Нужно к время 2015-04-24 16:51:06 округлить до 2015-04-24 16:50:00 или если 2015-04-24 16:53:06 то в 2015-04-24 16:55:00

Так как шаг проверки задачи 5 минут.

И т.е. к 2015-04-24 16:55:00 уже прибавить 480 минут

Помогите решить задачу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку 5 минут это 300 сек,

```
$time = round($timestamp / 300) * 300;
```

Если нужен текущий момент времени `$timestamp=time()`

Если у вас время в формате `dateTime` то `$timestamp= date_timestamp_get($date);` или `$timestamp=$date->getTimestamp();`

Comment: Объясните работу... Нужно к время 2015-04-24 16:51:06 округлить до 2015-04-24 16:50:00 или если 2015-04-24 16:53:06 то в 2015-04-24 16:55:00

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev в каком формате время? DateTime? или текст?

Comment: все сделал спасибо большое.